# White space around the entire page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I was developing my website, that's normally, but when I add a CSS doc in my html page, when we open website http://www.caiotoledo.com/, has a white space around the entire page.

I tried to set class body to container-fluid, because I'm using bootstrap, but that didn't solve my problem. I can't see anything that set this in the CSS, here is the code of CSS:

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
}

.range {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 1%;
}

.range input {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5px;
  height: 0.5px;
  appearance: none;
}

.range input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: -5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #135697;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.range input::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: -5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #135697;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.range input::-ms-thumb {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: -5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #135697;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0 !important;
}

.range input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #b2b2b2;
}

.range input::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #b2b2b2;
}

.range input::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #b2b2b2;
}

.range input:focus {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}

.range input::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

.range-labels {
  margin: -2.5% -6% 1%;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.range-labels li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 11.95%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range-labels li::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -23px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background: #b2b2b2;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.range-labels .active {
  color: #135697;
}

.range-labels .selected::before {
  background: #135697;
}

.range-labels .active.selected::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>HTML here please</div>
```

Comment: And your HTML looks like?  IF you have bootstrap classes on that it WILL matter here

Comment: You should add the minimum HTML code to see the problem and instead of using code block for HTML and CSS, use code snippet :D

Comment: I made a snippet to get you started but FWIW that is a lot of CSS that seems to be an excess for the question asked. BUT you SAID put a huge white space `body {
  padding: 100px;
}` with the padding

Comment: What do you think `body {padding: 100px;}` does?

Answer (score 3):

No need for the large padding on the body you have.

With bootstrap you can just set classes:
`<body class="m-0 p-0">`

```css
body {
  /*  NOT REALLY even needed here:
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
*/
}

.my-content {
  border: solid blue 1px;
  background-color: #0000FF20;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body class="m-0 p-0">
  <div class="my-content p-3">Here we go again!</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `body` element represents the content of an HTML document. There can be only one in a document.

An element's padding area is the space between its content and its border.

If you apply padding to the body such as `body { padding: 123px; }` then you’re asking the browser to add **123** space in pixels between the body’s borders and its content.

An HTML element is usually a box consisting of content + padding + border.

`padding: x` applies **x** all around the content
`padding: x y` applies **x** top the top, bottom and **y** to the left, right
`padding: w x y z` applies **w** to the top, **x** to the right, **y** to the bottom and **z** to the bottom.

You can also set them independently by calling *`padding-top`*, *`padding-right`*, *`padding-bottom`* and *`padding-left`*.

Therefore to remove the white space around the body: Remove the padding property and it’s value from the body selector.

There is no padding by default applied to the body.